# Python 3 array average calculation

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, precision

```
x=[1280.0, 2050.0, 709.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

num1=0
den1=0
num2=0
den2=0
for i in range(0,3):
    num1=num1+x[i]
    den1=den1+1
del i
for i in range(0,6):
    num2=num2+x[i]
    den2=den2+1

avgc1= num1/den1
avgc2= num2/den2
val = (100* avgc1 / avgc2)
print(val)
```

The value of variable `val` should be 200 but I get 199.99999999999997. Could someone please help me understand the reason.

At the same time, if I try the following, it returns 200.

```
y=4039.0
x1=y/3
x2=y/6
x3=100*x1/x2
print(x3)
```

Comment: Use `//` instead of `/`. (Your second example produces a floating point number as well when I test it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num1/den1` and `num2/den2` are computed with floating-point arithmetic. This includes rounding exact mathematical results to values representable in floating-point.

The result is that `avgc1` and `avgc2` may differ from their ideal mathematical values, and so does their quotient.

Answer (score 4):

I get `199.99999999999997` for both (Python version 3.7.1). The issue is due to rounding errors in floating point arithmetic.

You can do as @Josh Friedlander said and use the double `//`, but this will result in floor division which may not be what you want. To maintain higher accuracy you can try using `numpy` for division.

```
import numpy as np

y=4039
x1=np.divide(y,3)
x2=np.divide(y,6)
x3=100*np.divide(x1,x2)
print(x3)
```

Returns

```
200.0
```

Works for your other case too:

```
x=[1280.0, 2050.0, 709.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

num1=0
den1=0
num2=0
den2=0
for i in range(0,3):
    num1=num1+x[i]
    den1=den1+1
del i
for i in range(0,6):
    num2=num2+x[i]
    den2=den2+1

avgc1= np.divide(num1,den1)
avgc2= np.divide(num2,den2)
val = (100* np.divide(avgc1,avgc2))
print(val)
```

Returns

```
200.0
```

This is using `np.__version__` `1.15.4` for reference.

## Edit

As noted by @Mark Dickinson, order of operations is important. Putting parentheses around the division with pure Python will result in `200.0` without using `numpy`.

```
x=[1280.0, 2050.0, 709.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

num1=0
den1=0
num2=0
den2=0
for i in range(0,3):
    num1=num1+x[i]
    den1=den1+1
del i
for i in range(0,6):
    num2=num2+x[i]
    den2=den2+1

avgc1= num1 / den1
avgc2= num2 / den2

# use parentheses to perform division first
val = (100* (avgc1 / avgc2))
print(val)
```

Comment: NumPy is a red herring here: it doesn't make the slightest bit of difference, and there's no reason to expect it to. In both the pure Python case and the NumPy case, operations are being performed with IEEE 754 double precision arithmetic and correct rounding. The difference is in the next to last line, where you do the equivalent of `100 * (avgc1 / avgc2)`, and the OP does `100 * avgc1 / avgc2` (different order of operations). Replace that line with `np.divide(100 * avgc1, avgc2)` and you'll see the same result as the OP.